# How to scroll down properly in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I have used actions class to scroll down but when it scrolls down click code is not working:

```
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown).Build().Perform();
       
       
 driver.FindElement("//a[@href='http://automationpractice.com/index.php? 
 controller=order&step=1']").Click();
        
 //var ele = driver.FindElement(proceed);
 //actions.MoveToElement(ele).Click().Perform();
```

[image]
Please use below id pass to login:

ID : paul@xmail.com

Password : Pass123##

Comment: Can you provide the more detail, like the error, and  html source for the click  action.

Comment: Now it's working by using href, but is it right to use directly href in XPath?

Comment: I have edited the code in question, kindly take a look, plus link is added this error is on summary page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scrolling approsimatively with `PageDown`, you should perform scrolling to element in a precise way. Let me know if it works for you

```
var element = driver.FindElement("//a[@href='http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=order&step=1']");
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
element.Click();
```